How can I fully justify spaces inside enumitem description labels?
I will start with a picture that says more than a thousand words:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

What I currently see is this:

\begin{description}
    \item[A label] Antigravitationally fantastic umbrella-juggling kangaroos \linebreak{}unexpectedly navigated through marshmallow-infused spaghetti forests.
\end{description}

What I want is this:

\noindent
\textbf{A label} Antigravitationally fantastic umbrella-juggling kangaroos \linebreak{}unexpectedly navigated through marshmallow-infused spaghetti forests.

\end{document}

(The hard \linebreak{} is just inserted to make the inequal space widths in the label and the remaining text more visible. In reality, this effect is less visible but still causes more overfull/underfull hboxes for me, especially when using longer labels.)
How can I configure enumitem to use full justification for description labels, so that the spaces within the labels have dynamic widths like in the remainder of the items?
My second question is whether from an typographic/idiomatic point of view, anything speaks against this idea? Why are description labels in fully adjusted paragraphs not fully adjusted by default?

This is the best I have achieved so far:
\begin{description}[
    style=sameline, % adjust spaces WITHIN the label
    labelsep=0em % disable constant space AFTER label
]
    \item[A label % enforce regular space AT THE END of the label
    ] Antigravitationally fantastic umbrella-juggling kangaroos \linebreak{}unexpectedly navigated through marshmallow-infused spaghetti forests.
\end{description}

However, the second part of the solution (labelsep=0em & \item[... ]) looks like a hack, and I do not want to patch all the items in my document with this irregular space. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this or do I have to redefine \item conditionally?
Thanks in advance!

The setup would appear to cry out for suspending full justification of the first line in the description items. What's the use case for insisting on maintaining full justification of the first line?

The posted code does not produce the output shown. do you want the output from the code or the output shown in your image?

@Mico You mean like using \newline{} instead of \linebreak{} in this toy example? I can't help but find the result less pleasing than consistent full justification. Note that in practice, the space widths are not so extreme so there are rarely any overfull hboxes.

@DavidCarlisle Actually the code I have shown, this is an interesting side effect of loading (but not using) the blindtext package. I have added it above.

If nobody finds a better way, this is my solution for now:
\makeatletter
\newif\ifenit@regularlabelspaces
\enitkv@key{}{regularlabelspaces}[true]{%
    \enit@sepfrommarginfalse
    \enitkv@setkeys{enumitem}{style=sameline} % consistent spacing in labels and text -- but unfortunately not for labelsep, which we fix below
    \enit@calcset\labelsep\tw@{0em} % eliminate static labelsep
    \global\enit@regularlabelspacestrue
}
% introduce dynamic space after item instead
\let\originalitem\item
\renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
    \originalitem[#1]%
    \ifenit@regularlabelspaces%
        {\enit@format\ }%
        \ignorespaces%
    \fi
}
\let\origenddescription\enddescription
\renewcommand{\enddescription}{%
    \global\enit@regularlabelspacesfalse%
    \origenddescription%
}
\makeatother

Usage:
\begin{description}[regularlabelspaces]
    \item[A label] Antigravitationally fantastic umbrella-juggling kangaroos \linebreak{}unexpectedly navigated through marshmallow-infused spaghetti forests.
\end{description}


Why you like to have tipographical so bad list? What you like to achive  you can do without lists as you show in the second example in your question. For it you can design new environment based on minipage, for example. Be aware that main features of (La)TeX design is prevent such formating of text ...

As I have little knowledge about professional typesetting, I appreciate your comment. Why is this typography considered bad? Maybe I should have provided a more concrete example, I often use descriptions where the label is the beginning of the sentence (e.g., "\item[The tokenizer] is the first step... \item[The syntax parser] is the next step..."). Semantically, they are definitely lists with labels.

See https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/.Also see examples of tables in books of renowned publishers.

This is a good resource, but I don't see how I can apply this to descriptions in floating text.
